# How to access jcr:root with XPath JCR Query

Tags: xpath, aem, jcr

I would like to apply some java function on CQ5 `dialogs`. In the first step I search for dialog xml files in `myComponent folder` as follow:

```
NodeIterator tabRequiredFields = getQueryResult("/jcr:root/apps/myProject/pages/myComponent/dialog/jcr:root")
```

But this Query does not supply any results. crx Xpath tool does not show any result too see the follwoing picture:

[image]

my /jcr:root/apps/myProject/pages/myComponent/dialog.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
        stateful="false"
        title="Test"
        .....>
       <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="panel">
        ...
        ......
       </items>
      .....
   </jcr:root>
```

I can access `items` as follow

```
NodeIterator tabRequiredFields = getQueryResult("/jcr:root/apps/myProject/pages/myComponent/dialog/items")
```

This works fine. My Question is: why for `jcr:root`? how to check, if `jcr:root` exists?

Comment: I doubt if the dialog.xml would be rendered this way, at least when compared to my CQ instance this is not how my dialog.xml is structured. As far as i know, only the root node ('/') is exported as jcr:root in xml. So this appears a bit odd. Could you please mention which version of CQ you are using?

Comment: I use cq5.4 version and my dialog.xml is structured as mentioned :). I am wondering, that I can access all nodes but jcr:root

Comment: Well i use CQ 5.5. Why not try /jcr:root/apps/myProject/pages/myComponent/dialog instead of /jcr:root/apps/myProject/pages/myComponent/dialog/jcr:root?

Comment: Because not of all dialogs are named dialog.xml

Comment: In that case try /jcr:root/libs/foundation/components//element(*, cq:Dialog), this would return all dialogs irrespective of their names.

Comment: The problem is that not all of my dialogs are from the type cd:Dialog. Some of them are of the tpye cq:panel. The common property of the xml files is jcr:root. This is the reason why I'm trying to find a way to access jcr:root.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47654/discussion-between-rakhi4110-and-max-salah)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML element named `jcr:root` from the `dialog.xml` doesn't create `jcr:root` node in the repository. It's a special, reserved identifier and CRX Package Manager puts all properties and subnodes of this element into a node which name is the same as name of the file without extension (in your case it'll be `dialog`).

If it's not clear, use CRX DE, open `/apps/myProject/pages/myComponent` and see what you can find there. That's why you should add `/dialog` rather than `/jcr:root` to the end of your path.

If you want to find all dialogs, use the primary type `cq:Dialog`, as rakhi4110 suggests. Following query:

```
/jcr:root/apps/myProject/pages//element(*, cq:Dialog)
```

will return all dialogs from `/apps/myProject/pages` (and descendants).

Comment: This is clear. But I can not use /dialog because not all of my dialogs are named dialog. How would you identify the dialog.xml in this case?

Comment: `dialog.xml` is just a file in the CQ package. This particular name doesn't appear in the repository. You should use `cq:Dialog` primary type to list of dialogs from particular location, as rakhi4110 suggested in his comment.